# jQuery: getting parent of an element

Tags: jquery, dom

Consider below HTML:

```
<div class="votingButton">
       <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
</div>
```

As you can see parent of `i` element is `div`, but when I try to get parent of `i` via jQuery it gives me `i`:

```
$(function () {
     $('.icon-chevron-up').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).parent().html());
     });
 });
```

Above code gives me  `<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>`, I also tried these cases:

```
$(this).closest('.votingButton').html()
$(this).parents().html()
$(this).parents('.votingButton').html()
```

But still get `<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>`
Any idea?

Comment: The html of the parent container *is* `<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>`... I don't understand your question.

Comment: It returns you the correct value inside `parent` for the html. http://api.jquery.com/parent/ `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does. You're using `.parent().html()`. The HTML of the parent of your `.icon-chevron-up` element is:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
```

If you modified your HTML to:

```
<div class="votingButton">
    <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
    <span>Hello, world!</span>
</div>
```

The result of `$(this).parent().html()` would be:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
<span>Hello, world!</span>
```

Comment: I want all the HTML as result including parent element.

Answer (score 0):

The .html of the `div class="votingButton"` is

```
 <i class="icon-chevron-up"></i>
```

If you try to change the html() you might understand better. Try:

```
 $(function () {
      $('.icon-chevron-up').on('click', function () {
          $(this).parent().html("Removing the icon since that's the actual content of the parents div");
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this **(UPDATED AND TESTED)** :

```
$(function () {
     $('.icon-chevron-up').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).parent().wrap('<p/>').parent().html());
         $(this).parent().unwrap();
     });
 });
```

this will give you the html code of the parent (and its children inside it)

Comment: This will return *undefined*, as jQuery's returning `parent()` object has no `outerHTML` property. You'd need to use `parent()[0].outerHTML` instead. The question of how to get an element's outer HTML has been asked many times and already has a highly upvoted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4741203/1317805 - this answer also states why the `outerHTML` property should not be used.